# Google Dataflow: output message only to one of the PubSub topics based on condition

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

In my pipeline I want to output the messages to one of the PubSub topics based on the result from previous transformation. At the moment I'm sending output to the same topic:

```java
 SearchItemGeneratorOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(SearchItemGeneratorOptions.class);
 Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
 p.apply(...)
 //other transformations 
 .apply("ParseFile", new ParseFile()) // outputs PCollection<Message>, where each Message has a MessageType property with the name of the topic.
 .apply("WriteItemsToTopic", PubsubIO.writeStrings().to(options.getOutputTopic()));
```

And this is my Message object:

```java
class Message {
    private MessageType messageType;
    private String payload;
   //constructor, getters
}
```

My ParseFile transformer outputs PCollection and each Message object has a property messageType. Based on the messageType property I wanted to output to the different PubSub topics payload property of the Message. I read in [this](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/design-principles) article paragraph *Multiple transforms process the same PCollection* but still didn't get how I can apply it or other solutions in my case.

**Update**
thanks @Andrew for your solution.
I solved my issue by using TupleTag but approach is similar.
I created two different TupleTag objects in the main pipeline:

```
public static final TupleTag<String> full = new TupleTag<>("full");
public static final TupleTag<String> delta = new TupleTag<>("delta");
```

And then based on my condition I output the message in the DoFn with correct TupleTag:

```
TupleTag tupleTag = //assign full or delta TupleTag
processContext.output(tupleTag, jsonObject.toString());
```

And selected in the main pipeline from PCollectionTuple by each TupleTag to send to the Pub/Sub topics.

```
messages.get(full)
            .apply("SendToIndexTopic", PubsubIO.writeStrings().to(options.getOutputIndexTopic()));

messages.get(delta)
            .apply("SendToDeltaTopic", PubsubIO.writeStrings().to(options.getOutputDeltaTopic()));
```

The only thing to mention is that my TupleTag objects are static objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can partition your pipeline to publish messages to multiple Pub/Sub topics. Partitioning will allow you to separate messages and not duplicate them to different Pub/Sub topics. You'll need to know all of the Pub/Sub topics ahead of time. Reference: [Partition](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#partition).

Example:

```java
// partition pipeline

PCollectionList<Message> msgs = p.apply(Partition.of(2, new PartitionFn<Message>() {
    public int partitionFor(Message msg, int numPartitions) {
        // TODO: determine how to partition messages
        if (msg.messageType == "x") {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}));

// access partitions

PCollection<Message> partition1 = msgs.get(0);
partition1.apply("WriteItemsToTopic1", PubsubIO.writeStrings().to(options.getOutputTopic1()));

PCollection<Message> partition2 = msgs.get(1);
partition2.apply("WriteItemsToTopic2", PubsubIO.writeStrings().to(options.getOutputTopic2()));
```